# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project SpringData

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I was doing a spring data project jpa in maven and the following error has arisen and I have no idea why it is. This is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringData</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>SpringData</name>
</project>
```

Is a project with Spring Data Jpa.

I have no idea what the failure can be

**The error says:**

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. ene 20, 2019 11:21:09 AM
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper
>   logPersistenceUnitInformation INFO: HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: default   ...] ene 20, 2019 11:21:09 AM
>   org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core
>   {5.2.8.Final} ene 20, 2019 11:21:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found ene 20, 2019
>   11:21:09 AM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} ene 20, 2019 11:21:09 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
>    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect ene 20, 2019 11:21:10 AM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator
>   initiateService INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'clienteRepositorio': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   EntityPathResolver must not be null!  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
>     at principal.Principal.main(Principal.java:12) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityPathResolver must not be
>   null!     at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.setEntityPathResolver(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.createRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.doCreateRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.createRepositoryFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:270)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
>     ... 12 more
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 4.017s Finished at: Sun Jan 20 11:21:11 CET 2019 Final
>   Memory: 6M/245M
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project SpringData: Command execution failed. Process
>   exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

**And the ApplicationContext:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="dao"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="dominio" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>       
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BClientes" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**And Principal.java**

```
package principal;

import dao.ClienteRepositorio;
import dominio.Cliente;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        ClienteRepositorio clientes = (ClienteRepositorio) context.getBean("clienteRepositorio");

        Cliente cliente;

        Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente(1, "pwjuan", "Juan Alcaraz");
        Cliente cliente2 = new Cliente(2, "pwpedro", "Pedro Zamora");
        Cliente cliente3 = new Cliente(3, "pwluis", "Luis Valera");

        // Borramos todo, para no tener que ejecutar el script de la base cada vez
        for (Cliente c : clientes.findAll())
            clientes.delete(c);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Alta de clientes en proceso");
        clientes.save(cliente1);
        clientes.save(cliente2);
        clientes.save(cliente3);

      }


}
```

Project structure: https://gyazo.com/37d13670db39aa5c887ddb72f62574ef

Comment: Where is your `applicationContext.xml` located and is it named the correct way (exactly)?

Comment: I just put a gyazo at the end of everything

Comment: Please don't change your question so frequently. Writing an answer just to see you have solved one problem but updated the error log to show yet another problem is frustrating. Furthermore it isn't helpful for later readers of this (this isn't a chat platform) as they can't understand the answers anymore.

Comment: Ok, than you. :)

Comment: In the newest version of your question, please examine the error you got, it says: `EntityPathResolver must not be null!`. Search for the cause of this problem in the internet and if you can't find the solution come back and open up a new question.

Comment: Now, that's what I'm doing, usually asking here is my last option because I do not like to ask, but before it got out of hand. This failure leads me to persecute for a while. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your application context is missing the JPA schema reference.**

This line is giving you the location of the problem:

> Line 14 in XML document from class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 43; El
>   prefijo "jpa" para el elemento "jpa:repositories" no está enlazado.

And the solution is to properly reference the jpa schema:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    ...
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
            ...
            >
```

Note how your `context.xml` is missing the `xmlns:jpa` part.

Comment: Sorry, but the error changed, I updated the post with the latest

Answer (score 0):

Try organizing your files using the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      (put your .java files here)
    resources/
      applicationContext.xml
```

Have a look at the compiled sources (`target` folder or the `.jar` file - notice you can open the latter with a ZIP compatible archiver like 7-ZIP) and verify that your `applicationContext.xml` is indeed missing before changing the folder structure and is present after applying it and compiling the project.

Update for readers of this answer: the author has changed the question multiple times. Each time a completely new error was reported after fixing the previous one. This answer was one step in that journey, it allowed the system to actually find the `applicationContext.xml` at runtime.

Comment: I moved the applicationContext to src/ main/resources and the error changed. The post is now updated